# How to fix the output 'undefined' when searching an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I was trying to make a javascript code that searches inside an objects array for text and then deletes the whole index (the index that includes the text property) but the code failed and always return 'undefined' so i wanted to get some help.

```
const todos = [{
    text: 'wake up',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play csgo',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play minecraft',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'learn javascript',
    completed: false
}]



let todo = function (todo, todoText) {
    return todo.find(function (text, index) {
        if (todo.text.toLowerCase() === todoText.toLowerCase()) {
            todo.splice(index, 1);
        }
    })
}

let deleteTodo = todo(todos, 'wake up');
console.log(deleteTodo);
```

i was expecting this output:

```
[{
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play csgo',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play minecraft',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'learn javascript',
    completed: false
}]
```

but the output was actually `'undefined'`

Comment: You are returning the return value from `Array.prototype.find()` but your callback doesn't return anything so `find()` finds **nothing** (ie `undefined`)

Comment: You shouldn't modify the array you're searching.

Comment: Don't use splice just return value from find callback, or use filter to remove the unwanted values

Comment: Typo: `todo.text` should be `text.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.find()` requires the function to return a truthy value when the condition is matched. Your function doesn't return anything, it just splices the element out, so `find()` never returns the matching element.

You just need to add `return true;` after splicing the element.

```js
let todo = function(todo, todoText) {
  todoText = todoText.toLowerCase();
  return todo.find(function(text, index) {
    if (text.text.toLowerCase() === todoText) {
      todo.splice(index, 1);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })
}

const todos = [{
    text: 'wake up',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play csgo',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play minecraft',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'learn javascript',
    completed: false
}];

let deleteTodo = todo(todos, 'wake up');
console.log("Object that was removed:", deleteTodo);
console.log("Array that remains:", todos);
```

Earlier I wrote that you shouldn't modify the array while searching. But the specification of `Array.prototype.find` allows this, because it extracts the element from the array before calling the test function. Since you're only modifying the array when the match is found, it won't impact the rest of the iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i ran your code it output this 
` { text: 'wake up', completed: true }
[ { text: 'get some food', completed: false },
  { text: 'play csgo', completed: false },
  { text: 'play minecraft', completed: true },
  { text: 'learn javascript', completed: false } ] `

but i want the object with the text: 'wake up' to be completely removed from the array.

Comment: It is removed from the array. There are two `console.log()` statements. One is showing the object that was removed, the other is showing the array with the object removed.

Comment: i really didnt notice omg thanks man for the help it actually works

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of immutability, I would instead **filter** the array to produce a new one without the matching records, ie

```js
return todo.filter(({text}) => todoText.localeCompare(text, undefined, {
  sensitivity: 'base'
}))
```

[`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) will return a `0` value (*falsy*) if the strings match (ignoring case) or `-1` / `+1` (*truthy*) if they do not. This can be used to let [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) know whether or not to include the entry in the final array.

```js
const todos = [{
    text: 'wake up',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play csgo',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play minecraft',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'learn javascript',
    completed: false
}]

let todo = (todos, todoText) =>
  todos.filter(({ text }) => text.localeCompare(todoText, undefined, {
    sensitivity: 'base'
  }))

let deleteTodo = todo(todos, 'WAKE UP');
console.log(deleteTodo);
```

Comment: What i am understanding from code is op is trying to remove matching todos, i think negation should be used here

Comment: @CodeManiac I'm cheating somewhat by using the implicit Boolean inversion of `String.prototype.localeCompare()`. If the strings are equal, it returns `0` which will filter out that value

Comment: He wants the function to return the matching todo, and also remove it from the list. This just returns the new list, but not the matching todo.

Comment: @Barmar that's not clear from the question or the code in the question so I made an assumption

Comment: His use of `find()` is strongly suggestive of trying to return the element.

Comment: @Barmar But the expected output doesn't seems to say so, it is just showing the values which do not match the passed text, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Barmar I'm more than happy to be wrong about the expected output

Comment: Good point. My answer returns the found element and modifies the array in place, so you can get both outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a better function to solve it: filter

```
let res = todos.filter( elem => elem.text.toLowerCase() !== 'wake up');
```

And if you want it to be a function, it would something like:

```
let result = (todos, todoText) => {
  return todos.filter( elem => elem.text.toLowerCase() !== todoText.toLowerCase() );
}
console.log(result(todos, 'wake up'));
```

Comment: Note: OP seems to want to compare the text without case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

Not that I would use `.find` because of backward compatibility, but if you insist:

```js
const todos = [{
    text: 'wake up',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play csgo',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play minecraft',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'learn javascript',
    completed: false
}];
let deleteTodo = function(todos, todoText){
  var e = todos.find(function(text){
    if(text.text.toLowerCase() === todoText.toLowerCase()){
      return true;
    }
  });
  return todos.splice(todos.indexOf(e), 1);
}
console.log(deleteTodo(todos, 'wake up')); // deleted
console.log(todos); // altered array
```

Here is a backward compatible version:

```js
var todos = [{
    text: 'wake up',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play csgo',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play minecraft',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'learn javascript',
    completed: false
}];
function TodoWorker(todos){
  this.todos = todos;
  this.remove = function(text){
    for(var i=0,a=this.todos,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
      if(a[i].text === text){
        return a.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
var tw = new TodoWorker(todos);
console.log(tw.remove('play csgo')); // deleted element
console.log(tw.todos); // altered array
console.log(tw.remove('play minecraft')); // deleted element
console.log(tw.todos); // altered array - what you should be doing
```

You can see the second approach is both backward compatible and allows you to leave out your `todos` argument in it's `.remove` method.

Comment: `find()` doesn't return the index, it returns the element.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used `.find` that often. I'm surprised I got the expected result. I fixed it, though. I will supply a backward compatible version as well. Hold on... I need a sip of coffee.

Comment: It was only working by accident, because the matching element was the first element in the array. You had `return index` when it matched, and `index` was `0`, which is falsey. So `find()` didn't find a match and returned `undefined`. Then when you called `todos.splice(i, 1)`, the undefined value of `i` was converted to `0` by `splice()`.

Comment: Thanks `@Barmar`, I realized that and gave you points for your first comment. Of course... someone had to vote you up again. The rich get richer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code can work with a little modification:

```js
const todos = [{
    text: 'wake up',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play csgo',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play minecraft',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'learn javascript',
    completed: false
}]



 function todo(todo, todoText) {
     let result = [];
     for (let index = 0; index < todo.length; index++) {
      
        if (todoText.toLowerCase() === todo[index].text.toString().toLocaleLowerCase()) {
        console.log("the deleted todo :",todo[index].text.toString().toLocaleLowerCase())
    }else{
            result.push(todo[index])
        }

     }
     return result;
}

let deleteTodo = todo(todos, 'wake up');
console.log(deleteTodo);
```

I've changed the loop a little and the function, using another variable for storing the result.
Hope it helps